# SSR disabled for single page

Tags: nuxt.js, single-page-application, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs3

I got a simple Nuxt3 test spa with a `/user` page that is accessible only after login.

I want every other page to be prerendered server side while `/user` need to be hydrated on client side, so I set my `nuxt.config.ts`:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  routeRules: {
    "/user": { ssr: false },
  },
})
```

Building via `npm run generate` gives no error, but after logging in even if the page is correctly hydrated the browser console show the following error:
[image]

## Update #1

Tried `/user/*` wildcard as @kissu suggested didn't work, now building the app gives following error:

```
 WARN  Changing NODE_ENV from development to production, to avoid unintended behavior.                         12:43:15 PM

Nuxt 3.7.4 with Nitro 2.6.3                                                                                    12:43:15 PM
ℹ Building client...                                                                                          12:43:18 PM
ℹ vite v4.4.9 building for production...                                                                      12:43:18 PM
ℹ ✓ 188 modules transformed.                                                                                  12:43:20 PM
ℹ .nuxt/dist/client/manifest.json                                  3.28 kB │ gzip:  0.54 kB                   12:43:20 PM
ℹ .nuxt/dist/client/_nuxt/error-500.c5df6088.css                   1.95 kB │ gzip:  0.74 kB                   12:43:20 PM
ℹ .nuxt/dist/client/_nuxt/error-404.7fc72018.css                   3.63 kB │ gzip:  1.12 kB                   12:43:20 PM
ℹ .nuxt/dist/client/_nuxt/_plugin-vue_export-helper.c27b6911.js    0.09 kB │ gzip:  0.10 kB                   12:43:20 PM
ℹ .nuxt/dist/client/_nuxt/unauthenticated.600f11ff.js              0.13 kB │ gzip:  0.14 kB                   12:43:20 PM
ℹ .nuxt/dist/client/_nuxt/authenticated.d215a98b.js                0.14 kB │ gzip:  0.14 kB                   12:43:20 PM
ℹ .nuxt/dist/client/_nuxt/index.2526276b.js                        0.21 kB │ gzip:  0.19 kB                   12:43:20 PM
ℹ .nuxt/dist/client/_nuxt/user.ec33d6aa.js                         0.27 kB │ gzip:  0.21 kB                   12:43:20 PM
ℹ .nuxt/dist/client/_nuxt/vue.f36acd1f.d6992c47.js                 0.39 kB │ gzip:  0.26 kB                   12:43:20 PM
ℹ .nuxt/dist/client/_nuxt/login.e74dd172.js                        0.91 kB │ gzip:  0.50 kB                   12:43:20 PM
ℹ .nuxt/dist/client/_nuxt/register.a5e8f2d0.js                     1.24 kB │ gzip:  0.54 kB                   12:43:20 PM
ℹ .nuxt/dist/client/_nuxt/error-500.2879a701.js                    1.97 kB │ gzip:  1.04 kB                   12:43:20 PM
ℹ .nuxt/dist/client/_nuxt/error-404.e65df127.js                    2.31 kB │ gzip:  1.19 kB                   12:43:20 PM
ℹ .nuxt/dist/client/_nuxt/entry.5f25358b.js                      187.21 kB │ gzip: 70.80 kB                   12:43:20 PM
ℹ ✓ built in 1.91s                                                                                            12:43:20 PM
✔ Client built in 1924ms                                                                                      12:43:20 PM
ℹ Building server...                                                                                          12:43:20 PM
ℹ vite v4.4.9 building SSR bundle for production...                                                           12:43:20 PM
ℹ ✓ 90 modules transformed.                                                                                   12:43:21 PM
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/error-404-styles.1e0dde27.mjs           0.15 kB                                     12:43:21 PM
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/error-500-styles.cf4b3e80.mjs           0.15 kB                                     12:43:21 PM
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/styles.mjs                                    0.35 kB                                     12:43:21 PM
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/_plugin-vue_export-helper-cc2b3d55.js   0.25 kB │ map:   0.13 kB                    12:43:21 PM
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/index-449efe46.js                       0.73 kB │ map:   0.11 kB                    12:43:21 PM
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/authenticated-641a2c4c.js               0.78 kB │ map:   0.52 kB                    12:43:21 PM
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/unauthenticated-25f34f2b.js             0.78 kB │ map:   0.52 kB                    12:43:21 PM
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/index-6a088328.js                       0.98 kB │ map:   4.83 kB                    12:43:21 PM
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/island-renderer-27b345f2.js             1.21 kB │ map:   1.38 kB                    12:43:21 PM
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/user-4c8c3e6d.js                        1.22 kB │ map:   0.53 kB                    12:43:21 PM
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/login-71ed365c.js                       1.48 kB │ map:   1.62 kB                    12:43:21 PM
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/register-068a0776.js                    1.76 kB │ map:   2.03 kB                    12:43:21 PM
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/error-500-styles-1.mjs-8fa81fcc.js      2.17 kB │ map:   0.12 kB                    12:43:21 PM
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/error-500-c4b1d7aa.js                   3.27 kB │ map:   3.78 kB                    12:43:21 PM
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/error-404-styles-1.mjs-e0837f4f.js      3.86 kB │ map:   0.12 kB                    12:43:21 PM
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/error-404-883fca85.js                   4.13 kB │ map:   5.82 kB                    12:43:21 PM
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/server.mjs                                   86.29 kB │ map: 210.91 kB                    12:43:21 PM
ℹ ✓ built in 829ms                                                                                            12:43:21 PM
✔ Server built in 842ms                                                                                       12:43:21 PM

[12:43:21 PM]  ERROR  ENOENT: no such file or directory, copyfile '/home/node/app/.nuxt/dist/client/_nuxt/_plugin-vue_export-helper.c27b6911.js' -> '/home/node/app/.output/public/_nuxt/_plugin-vue_export-helper.c27b6911.js'

 



[12:43:21 PM]  ERROR  ENOENT: no such file or directory, copyfile '/home/node/app/.nuxt/dist/client/_nuxt/_plugin-vue_export-helper.c27b6911.js' -> '/home/node/app/.output/public/_nuxt/_plugin-vue_export-helper.c27b6911.js'
```

Comment: How do you preview the page? Also, did you tried adding some wildcard ( `/user/*`) to the path?

Comment: @kissu i didn' tried wildcards yet, and as i told i viewed the page in the browser

Comment: Did you ran `npm run preview`?

Comment: i generated static files via `npm run generate` and served via nginx; since the final spa will be served in production without a nodejs backend i'm trying to keep development as alike as possible

Comment: You need to configure MIME types for your nginx server then. Still, I recommend trying to use `npm run preview` to see if that one works locally at least for a faster debugging. And I meant a [double-wildcard](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/rendering#hybrid-rendering).